# SQL Server print statement returning null in Data Table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2016

I am authenticating account using **if exists** query and print true if the account is authenticate else print false.

```
if exists (select email, password 
           from client 
           where email = 'email@example.com' and password = '123') 
    print 'true' 
else 
    print 'false';
```

It prints true or false in SQL Server Management Studio, but when I authenticate account from my website, the data table rows and columns count is always 0. What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

```
public bool ExecuteReader(string query)
{
        bool result = false;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Close();

        dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count == 1 && dt.Columns.Count == 1)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "true")
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                result = false;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your query does not return anything.. it just prints true or false. So executing that query via ADO.NET will not get you anything in datatable. You should have query like 'SELECT email from client where...` this will return email in the datatable. Then you can check for the number or columns an rows in the datatable to authenticate user. There are other issues with your code though but for now you can go with this simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PRINT` returns a message rather than a result set (which requires a SqlConnection.InfoMessage event handler). USE a `SELECT` statement instead to load the result into a `DataTable`:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1
FROM dbo.client
WHERE email = 'email@example.com' AND password = '123'
)
SELECT 'true'
ELSE
SELECT 'false';
```

Answer (score 0):

You query uses print 'true' else print 'false'.  The print statement does not return a row of data; use select 'true' else select 'false' instead.

In addition, you are closing the connection before executing the command which fills the data table; try moving the con.Close() after the da.Fill(dt).

Answer (score 0):

try this one and also the close code after the everything is done.

```
SELECT
  ISNULL((SELECT
    'true'
  FROM client
  WHERE email = 'email@example.com'
  AND password = '123')
  , 'false')
```